# Where are WinEdt acronyms explained?

Tags: winedt

I am a newcomer to WinEdt 7.1  Where can I find a simple explanation for terms such as PDFTeX, PDFLaTeX, and PDFTexify?

Comment: These terms aren’t specific to WinEdt. You might fight some information in [Glossary of TeX and LaTeX terms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58431), but this is still very much a work in progress.

Comment: Other than that, you’ll find questions about the specific terms here on tex.sx, with some answers being more newbie-friendly and others less: [What's the difference between pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41031) ~ [Which "TeX" should one use?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22823) ~ [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36) ... Figuring out what all the terms with “TeX” in them mean is probably one of the hardest parts when delving into this world.

Answer (score 3):

The following, rather than an answer, wants to be a clarification...

While Doncherry is right about PDFTeX and PDFLaTeX, the meaning of PDFTeXify in WinEdt is not what one might think at a first glance.

In fact (taking the term from MiKTeX `texify` executable), in WinEdt has been implemented a quite sophisticated algorithm which, with one mouse-click, performs all needed compilations to get a fully compiled document.

In other words, when in WinEdt you press the button `PDFTeXify` (or `TeXify` when you want a dvi workflow) you launch an algorithm that takes care of compiling the document itself, as well as bibliographies, indexes, glossaries, etc., to get a fully compiled document.

These commands don't necessarily make use of MiKTeX `texify` program. In fact, they work both with MiKTeX and TeX Live and also succeed where MiKTeX `texify` fails (eg. when launching `biber`).

Moreover, these commands are customizable so you can decide, for example, to use `makeglossaries` for compiling glossaries.

Some additional packages available at the site [winedt.org](http://www.winedt.org) also permit to add additional functionalities to the above commands like compiling nomenclatures, inline asymptote figures, etc.