# What is the difference between compiling options in texmaker and wich one to choose

Tags: compiling, texmaker, ubuntu

i began learning lateX 3 days ago to make my training report ...
i'm using texmaker in UBUNTU 14.04
I was compiling my files using quick build option in compilation menu and i was wondering what do they do the other options

> latex , pdflatex , lualatex , etc.

and what is the difference between each one and when to choose one beside the other 
Thanks

Comment: See [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/35864), [I am new to TeX. Should I use LaTeX, XeLaTeX, …?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42628/35864) and [Which “TeX” should one use?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22823/35864)