# How to check what I'm using in my environment

Tags: pdftex, compiling, mac, editors, vscode

I use VS code with the Latex workshop on Mac and it works perfectly fine when writing a paper. But I don't understand  "pdflatex", "mactex", "texlive" or something other people are saying

What are the essential components to compile a paper using Mac? How can I check what is working behind my VS code? (I don't remember what I installed so far to make my environment possible )

Comment: What's your question? If you installed LaTeX workshop, then you're using LaTeX workshop, no?

Comment: @user202729 Oh, you mean I can write a paper using Latex only if I instal VS code and Latex workshop?

Comment: No that just gives you an editor to write the source code, you need a tex system (usually mactex on a mac) to actually process your document.

Comment: As with every other coding project, there is always an editor (VS code in this case) and the actual program that processes the code you write in this editor (`pdflatex` in this case). TeXLive is a distribution, that is, a software bundle that contains `pdflatex` but also a lot of helpful other software and packages. And MacTeX finally is an application that installs TeXLive on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of LaTeX-Workshop is in the `settings.json` file, you can open it to see all the tools and recipes you have configured. And you could also see the recipes from the TeX badge in the left sidebar.

[image]

- TeX Live is a TeX distribution (type `tex -v` in terminal to see the version)
- LaTeX is a "TeX format" (a set of TeX macros), TeX Live includes LaTeX and several more TeX formats.
- MacTeX is a package which installs TeX Live on the Macintosh (see https://tug.org/mactex/)
- `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` are compilation commands (for differences, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22825/241621)

Comment: Thank you for the detail. In my badge, "latexmk" alone appears. Which means I've done all things with this?

Comment: Yeah, it is.@SpaceTAKA

Comment: thank you. latexmk is for what (guess it's kinda compilation commands)? Don't I need Tex live or something?

Comment: latexmk can compile your document automatically. For its usage, please see its manual https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/CTAN/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf

Comment: I guess you have installed texlive already on your mac.

Comment: I see, how can I check that? and is it Okay to uninstall mactex now?

Comment: @SpaceTAKA see the first bullet item in my answer to check whether you have installed texlive or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149899/discussion-between-stephen-and-spacetaka).